# How to make Tomcat 7 log debugging info?

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7

Tomcat 7 takes more than 21 minutes to start:

```
ene 09, 2013 10:01:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1290787 ms
```

When it finishes it says that it's scanning JARs that don't contain TLDs:

```
ene 09, 2013 10:59:39 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
```

A paste of the entire log can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1520106/).

After searching the error, I discovered that [someone had resolved the same issue](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/tomcat-7-scans-all-jars-for-tlds.html) by modifying `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties` to log more verbose information.

But when I set `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level` to `FINE` as suggested in the link, the output of my log remains unchanged.

How can I make Tomcat 7 log more?

Comment: I'm guessing the English language version of that error message would be something like `Jul 23, 2015 1:16:43 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.`

Answer (score 1):

In tomcat 7, logging.properties contains an entry: `#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE`, which is commented out by default. Would removing the comment help give you the information you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

From Tomcat 7 documentation (at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default) ):

> The default `logging.properties` in the JRE specifies a `ConsoleHandler` that routes logging to  `System.err`. The default `conf/logging.properties` in Apache Tomcat also adds several `FileHandlers` that write to files.
>
> A handler's log level threshold is `INFO` by default and can be set using `SEVERE`, `WARNING`, `INFO`, `CONFIG`, `FINE`, `FINER`, `FINEST` or `ALL`. You can also target specific packages to collect logging from and specify a level.
>
> Here is how you would set debugging from Tomcat. You would need to ensure the ConsoleHandler's (or FileHandler's') level is also set to collect this threshold, so `FINEST` or `ALL` should be set. Please refer to java.util.logging  documentation in the JDK for the complete details:
>
> ```
> org.apache.catalina.level=FINEST
> ```